# How to check the number of readonly TextBoxes in Asp.Net MVC3 using Jquery

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

My Application is in Asp.Net MVC3.I have many TextBoxes in my View.And there are few readonly Textboxes in it.I want that the readonly textboxes should be displayed with a different Background color.
Im successfully able to change the Background color of all textboxes in my View.
Below is my code.

```
var allInputs = $(":input");
allInputs.css("background", "red");
```

This is how all textboxes background is changed.But i want that only readonly textboxes should be changed.
How can i check the readonly property and set the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use allInputs, Your code will be like this :

```
$(":input[readonly=readonly]").css("myProperty", "myValue");
```

Answer (score 2):

It was Pretty simple and its working great.

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
          $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
            var myText= $(this).attr('readonly');
            if (myText) {
                $(this).css("background", "yello");
            }
        });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as I know, readonly text boxes is defined using **readonly** attribute like below:

```
<input type="text" readonly="readonly" />
```

So you can change the background color of readonly textboxes using attribute selector in jQuery.

Here's the the jQuery script:

```
$(":input[readonly=readonly]").css("background", "red");
```